# On Mac OS X, why doesn't the version of maven bundled with NetBeans 8.0 IDE do a clean / build?

Tags: maven, netbeans

I'm running OS X Mavericks.  Then I:

1. Downloaded / installed NetBeans 8.0 IDE ("All" download).
2. Opened my maven project in the IDE.
3. Select project name.
4. Attempted Clean and Build.  No go.
5. Attempted to generate dependency tree from maven.  No go.

It appears the version of maven bundled with NetBeans 8.0 is not working.

Preferences shows the v. 3.0.5 of maven is bundled with the IDE.  Here is
the path, I think, to the bundled version:

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 8.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven
```

To confirm the project is valid, I then downloaded / installed my own, local
instance of Maven (v. 3.2.3).  From the shell, I am able to clean / build 
install fine.  IE, the project is sound.

Something is awry with the IDE.  I've searched Google and Yahoo, to no avail.

Comment: what exactly does No GO in step 4 mean?

Comment: "No go" is an English idiom that means:  "It did not work out as expected."

Comment: Right, but it's very hard to provide any insight when neither the expectation nor the actual state is described.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the short explanation of what is going on is that there is
an initialization bug in NetBeans 8.0.  Here is what I did to get my
instance of the IDE to start using the bundled version of maven:

1. Downloaded / installed Apache Tomcat 7.x.
2. In the NetBeans IDE, went to Services>Servers, and added Tomcat.
3. In the NetBeans IDE, went to Projects, selected my project, right-clicked, and chose Properties.
4. In the Project Properties dialog, I selected Run, and chose Apache Tomcat for the Server, added a Context Path, and pressed OK.
5. Then I added a suitable custom-context to /path/to/apache-tomcat-7/conf/Catalina/localhost/myproject.xml, where I specified a reference to my workspace-instance of my project's war-file.
6. In addition to all of these steps, I also had to make certain permission-changes for Tomcat configuration files.  You will have to figure this step out depending on your installation.

Finally, in the Projects window, I selected my project, right-clicked and selected Run.
Mysteriously, the bundled instance of maven started working.

I hope these steps can help others, as well as the NetBeans team resolve the initialization issue.